# How can I show the value inside this std object

Tags: php, object

I have an object from which I want to display a value.

My object looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Orionstraat 11, 3235 TE Rockanje, Netherlands
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Woonkreek 56, 3206 GT Spijkenisse, Netherlands
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [elements] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [distance] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [text] => 25.2 km
                                            [value] => 25195
                                        )

                                    [duration] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [text] => 30 mins
                                            [value] => 1796
                                        )

                                    [status] => OK
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => OK
)
```

I want to return the `value` inside  `distance`.

So I did this:

```
foreach($distancedecoded as $route){
  $distance = $route->elements->distance->value;
}
echo $distance;
```

But this shows nothing, why is that?

I've also tried:

```
$distance = $route[2]->elements->distance->value;
```

When I get an array instead of an object:

```
$distancedecoded = json_decode($getdistance, true);

foreach($distancedecoded as $route){
  $distance = $route[2][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
  $routearray[] = $route;
}
```

I get these warnings:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'elements' in /home/site/public_html/_extern/site/includes/getzip.php on line 105

Warning: Illegal string offset 'distance' in /home/site/public_html/_extern/site/includes/getzip.php on line 105

Warning: Illegal string offset 'value' in /home/site/public_html/_extern/site/includes/getzip.php on line 105
```

var_dump of `$distancedecoded`

```
object(stdClass)#35 (4) {
  ["destination_addresses"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(45) "Orionstraat 11, 3235 TE Rockanje, Netherlands"
  }
  ["origin_addresses"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(46) "Woonkreek 56, 3206 GT Spijkenisse, Netherlands"
  }
  ["rows"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#36 (1) {
      ["elements"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#37 (3) {
          ["distance"]=>
          object(stdClass)#38 (2) {
            ["text"]=>
            string(7) "25.2 km"
            ["value"]=>
            int(25195)
          }
          ["duration"]=>
          object(stdClass)#39 (2) {
            ["text"]=>
            string(7) "30 mins"
            ["value"]=>
            int(1796)
          }
          ["status"]=>
          string(2) "OK"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
}
```

Comment: Are you using `json_decode` to get this information? If so, set the second parameter to `true` so it will be generated as array instead of object.

Comment: I think it should be `$route[2][0]->elements[0]->distance->value` if you assign the total array to $route;

Comment: @mulquin Yes I am but then when I change my code I get an illegal string offset warning on elements distance and value. Ill add the code to my question.

Comment: Could you please provide a new `var_dump` of `$distancedecoded`

Comment: @JackSkeletron This also shows nothing. I added a 1 to my echo to see if it was hidden maybe, but the 1 is shown, there is nothing in $distance.

Comment: @mulquin Yes I added it.

Comment: After your update it should be `$distancedecoded->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$destination = $distancedecoded->destination_addresses[0];
$origin = $distancedecoded->origin_addresses[0];

$distance = $distancedecoded->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value;
$duration = $distancedecoded->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->value;
```